# Production, development, staging configs in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've read several tutorial on the subject, but still don't completely get what's expected from the developer wanting to make ZF2 app environment aware:

http://blog.evan.pro/environment-specific-configuration-in-zend-framework-2
http://www.spiffyjr.me/2012/06/17/how-does-configuration-work-in-zf2/comment-page-1/

ZF2 s not aware of environment concept by design -  it's left to a developer to implement. I'm not entirely clear on how it's supposed to be done...

Reading through Evan's post it seems like there are 2 mechanism - and preferred one is **not to use APPLICATION_ENV constant**,  just .local, .global files?

How should that work? Could someone describe a process they go though to make ZF2 environment aware? And what you do when code is to be pushed to different environment?

---

It seems like the idea is right now to have for ex: **module1.local.php.dist-testing**, **module1.local.php.dist-production**, **module1.local.php.dist-development** and when code is moved to different environment the idea is that these should be copy-renamed for that environment and passwords filled in manually? Am I correct?

Comment: There is another post by Evan, too, where he explains how to make ZF1-like env-specific configuration work > http://blog.evan.pro/environment-specific-configuration-in-zend-framework-2
Both are acceptable, the new stuff is simply a preference of some people. In the company world, most often configuration will be handled by the developers, as the server guys dont wanna touch our configs, so the env-specific approach is still the 'best' way to go

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is that you provide some sensible default configuration with your application, but you do not store anything for a concrete environment with your code, nor in your version control system.

If you have for example two servers, one for production, one for development, you provide only the configuration details for one single environment in such a .local file. This way, your development server cannot know e.g. the master password for the production database. So it cannot accidentally happen that you get a new development server, and somebody forgets to set APPLICATION_ENV, and you start developing and mess up your production database, because the application knew the passwords.

Or the other way around, a new production server cannot accidentally access the development database.

So your application is aware of the environment automatically by reading the file that is present - and there is only one file per environment present that has all the details.

This puts the burden of ensuring that the correct file is present to the administrator - or the puppet script that configures everything. But the environment specific configuration will not be deployed within the application.

Comment: How would deployment to another server with different environment look like? One checks out code, renames dist file and fills in passwords manually?

Comment: "This puts the burden of ensuring that the correct file is present to the administrator - or the puppet script that configures everything" - your answer totally belong to ZF2 docs. Thank you. Much clearer now.

Comment: I believe deploying means to grab all application files from version control, add the appropriate local.php files from a different source, and push everything to the server. Or to avoid deleting the local.php files that are still present in the current version.